# Display Window on top of any app AND status bar but not appear on lock screen?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

To display a window on top of the status bar (and accept touch events), it seems `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` is the only way to go.

However, such a window will also appear on the lock screen, which I do not want to happen.

Is there some other way to achieve this?

If not, is there a way to listen to the event where the lockscreen becomes visible, so that I can hide the window programmatically?

Please note: the app does *not* have an `Activity` context.